# I need help understanding modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I need help understanding modular arithmetic. I know that modular arithmetic is instead of going to one o´clock you go to 13 o´clock but Im not sure. I got this off of wikipedia but anyone can put an answer on there. Am I correct? I need help understanding modular arithmetic. Are there multiple modular arithmetic? I need help understanding modular arithmetic.

Comment: Make your question more specific please

Comment: Please look at my profile before voting, answering it or commenting

Comment: How would I make it more specific?

Comment: I don know much more about modular arithmetic

Answer (score 3):

Modular arithmetic is basically being concerned about remainders. We write $12 \equiv 5 \pmod{7}$ because the remainder when $12$ is divided by $7$ is $5.$ The clock analogy gives a perfect way to picture this.

You're at a Navy hospital, walking around, and you see an announcement for a talk to be given at 1500 hours. What time is that? Well, the military (and some countries around the world) work on a 24-hour clock, so you'd have to work modulo 12. In particular,

$$ 15 \equiv 3 \pmod{12}$$

so you'd go to this talk at 3:00.

There are many tricks to modular arithmetic that are best learned by practice. The best way to learn is by doing, so start small.

Comment: In a Navy hospital, 1500 hours is called 6 bells. So 1500 hours is 3 (mod 12) which is 3 mod 4 times two (it advances one bell every 1/2 hour) to make 6. Still an exercise in modular arithmetic but a little more complicated.